# Types of crushing

Tags: process-engineering, terminology, crushing

What are the different types of crushing (not crushers)?

I know there's impact crushing, I think there is also pressure crushing and absrasive/friction crushing. Basically, what I am looking for is an overview of all the kinds of crushing actions (if you can call it that) that exist. I know there was a list in my school book but I don't have access to it anymore.

Comment: You might just have to look up the different type of crushers to find out the method each uses to crush: hammer, impact, rolls, jaw, cone & gyratory. Ultimately the four processes of crushing are impaction, tension, compression, shearing & attrition (a combination of impaction & grinding).